# Displaying specific number of records from text file

Tags: c#

Im having an issue loading just 3 records from the text file into a datagridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
           {
               if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && radioButton1.Checked)
               {
                   System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
                   string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split('|');
                   List<string> list = new List<string>();
                   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                   foreach (string c in columnnames)
                   {
                       dt.Columns.Add(c);
                   }
                   string newline;
                   while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                       string[] values = newline.Split('|');
                       for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                       {
                           dr[i] = values[i];

                       }

                       dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                   }
                   file.Close();
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
               }

           }
```

Im trying to have someone select a radio button such as "show 3 records" and open a text file. Then it would list the 3 records only in a datagridview. I can get the file to load the file but can't figure out how to make it only show 3 records from the text file. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Count the lines you're reading in your `while`, and stop when it's read the numbers you want to read. (BTW, text files don't have *records*, they have lines. Databases have records.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! im still pretty new to C# so my terminology gets mixed up sometimes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the number lines of read and then exit the read-load when it reaches 3 lines.

```
int maxLines = 3;
string newline;
while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null && --maxLines >= 0)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: I added this to my while loop and it worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var records = File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName).Take(3);

foreach(var record in records)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The advantages of this approach, is under the hood `ReadLines` creates an iterator and calls the plumbing for `StreamReader` and reads each line individually. When combined with `Take` it only reads and loads what is iterated( in this case the first 3 lines).

You can find (and follow) the source code here

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d989485a49fbbfd2.html

---

**Additional Resources**

[File.ReadLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Reads the lines of a file.

[Enumerable.Take(IEnumerable, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

Comment: The above will work, but it very inefficient because ReadLines allocates memory for each line in the file and is not lazy,

Comment: @RichardSchneider are you sure, as far as i knew it creates an iterator, and calls stream reader ReadLine (if i understand what you are saying), source code here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/d989485a49fbbfd2.html

Comment: Oops my bad, your code is NOT inefficient, `ReadLines` is lazy,  For some reason I was thinking about `ReadAllLines`

Comment: @RichardSchneider This is very helpful information I really appreciate it!